# how to prevent freezing get route on nodejs expresjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, express-router

I have a route like `http://localhost:3000/admin/video/edit/5` and the controller looks like this

```
 albumEdit: async (req, res) => {
        const editInfoId = req.params.id;
        await Movie.findOne({ where: { id: editInfoId } }).then((movie) => {
            if (movie) {
                res.render('admin/movies/edit', { title: 'Edit Movie On Page One', movie });
            }
        });
    },
```

for the testing purpose when I type the wrong id after `edit/` then the process is freezing after some time I am getting 500 errors.

how to prevent this if someone tries to break my app with the wrong id in the URL? I want something like if anyone tries to do this application redirect to an error page.

I am new in node js express js I need some info.

Comment: is there anyone to help me

Comment: Which `orm` are you using? If there is no record can be found in database, will `findOne ` throw exception?

Comment: I am using sequelize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route will freeze if `movie` is falsy or if `fineOne` results in an error because for both of these cases you don't send any response.

> after some time I am getting 500 errors.

If you run your node server behind a web server then this 500 is due to a timeout because your router does not send a response.

> how to prevent this if someone tries to break my app with the wrong id in the URL? I want something like if anyone tries to do this application redirect to an error page.

As with any programming language or code, make sure you handle all control flows and possible exceptions.

Besides that, if you use `await` you in most of the cases don't want to use `.then`.

```
   albumEdit: async (req, res) => {
     const editInfoId = req.params.id;

     try {
       let movie = await Movie.findOne({
         where: {
           id: editInfoId
         }
       })

       if (movie) {
         res.render('admin/movies/edit', {
           title: 'Edit Movie On Page One',
           movie
         });
       } else {
         // either the if is not necessary or you have to also handle the else cases
         
         // send some error response
         res.send('error')
       }
     } catch (err) {
       // send some error response
       res.send('error')
     }
  }
```

For completeness, this is how where you would need to do changes in your code, but as said above don't mix `await` and `then`:

```
 
   albumEdit: async (req, res) => {
     const editInfoId = req.params.id;

     try {
       await Movie.findOne({
         where: {
           id: editInfoId
         }
       }).then((movie) => {
         if (movie) {
           res.render('admin/movies/edit', {
             title: 'Edit Movie On Page One',
             movie
           });
         } else {
           // either the if is not necessary or you have to also handle the else cases
           
           // send some error response
           res.send('error')
         }
       });
     } catch (err) {
        // send some error response
        res.send('error')
     }
   }
```

Comment: Your first example really shouldn't be offered because mixing `await` and `.then()` the way you are is a confusing anti-pattern and not something you should be recommending or showing.   Either go all `.then()`, `.catch()` or all `await` and `try/catch`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I fully agree with that, that's why I added a second example. But I think that it changes the original code to much makes it sometimes hard to keep track of where the problems in the original code have been. But I change the order of the code blocks.

Comment: t.niese you are amazing, I understood my codding problem, I will take care in future `await then`